# text file in php with array

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fputs

I have a text file, data.txt, which contains the words in **"quotation marks"** and **separated by comma** like this:

> "e_mail","id_name","city","name","firstname","how","date"
>   "my@exemple.com","125","NY","Wells","tommy","","20130101"
>   "hisgoodemail@exemple.com","132","NY","Waits","John","","20120101"
>   "hisbadmailxemple.com","325","CH","Wells","Don","","20130101"
>   "goodmail3@exemple.com","222","NY","Wools","John","","20140101"

I will remove bad record/registration with the criterion of email, in my exemple it is 4. registration/record.

So I check the email format and I delete the wrong records which contains wrong format email.

After I would like put the new data in another file TEXT with the words **in "quotation marks" and separated by comma** like this:

> "e_mail","id_name","city","name","firstname","how","date"
>   "my@exemple.com","125","NY","Wells","tommy","","20130101"
>   "hisgoodemail@exemple.com","132","NY","Waits","John","","20120101"
>   "goodmail3@exemple.com","222","NY","Wools","John","","20140101"

But when I put the new data in the new file, its missing the **"quotation marks" and comma** :

```
    $fileData = 'data.txt';
if (($handle = fopen($fileData, "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',');

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $arrayContainsFileData = array
        (
            'e_mail' => $data[0],
            'id_name' => $data[1],
            'city' => $data[2],
            'name' => $data[3],
            'firstname' => $data[4],
            'how' => $data[5],
            'date' => $data[6]
        );
        //      var_dump($arrayContainsFileData);
        //        exit();

        $e_mail = $arrayContainsFileData['e_mail'];
        $e_mail = str_replace(' ', '', $e_mail);

        //remove bad record/registration with the criterion of email
        if(!VerifyEmailFormat($e_mail))
        { //echo 'bad format'';
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['e_mail']);
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['id_name']);
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['city']);
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['name']);
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['firstname']);
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['how']);
            unset($arrayContainsFileData['date']);
        }

        //          var_dump($arrayContainsFileData);
        //        exit();   

        $creationNewData = 'newCleanData' . date('Y_m_d__H_i_s__u'). '.txt';
        $openNewData = fopen($creationNewData, "a+");
        foreach ($arrayContainsFileData as $value)
            {
            fputs($openNewData, $value.' ');
            }
        fclose($openNewData);
    }
}
//__halt_compiler
```

how should I do putting the words in "quotation marks" and separated by comma ?

Comment: You're using fgetcsv() to read the data, use [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write it again

Comment: Just as an idea: if those e-mails are being taken from a form, then use on the form a regular expression to directly avoid people entering them in bad formats.

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan I'm guessing you mean using Javascript, in which case if Javascript is disabled the regex would be skipped and the form submitted, It's always best to check on the server too as those checks can't be disabled.

Comment: @Tom Hart Not at all, I'm talking about PHP regex in forms validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through each element of your array, you could use the php implode function (https://www.php.net/implode) to turn each array into a string first.

```
$str = '"' . implode('","', $arrayContainsFileData) . '"';
fputs($openNewData, $str);
```

Comment: Hi,

thanks cnick,

So I got: 
"my@exemple.com","125","NY","Wells","tommy","","20130101""""hisgoodemail@exemple.com","132","NY","Waits","John","","20120101""goodmail3@exemple.com","222","NY","Wools","John","","20140101"

Comment: This means that when there are bad email in this file (), It remove that bad record/registration so there are clear/empty records, 
so there is a empty in "quotation marks" 
and that is why I have: "20130101""""hisgoodemail@exemple.com"


So I added this line : 
$unset_emptyArray = str_replace ( '""' , '' , $str);
like this :

$openNewData = fopen($creationNewData, "a+");

$str = '"' . implode('","', $arrayContainsFileData) . '"';
$unset_emptyArray = str_replace ( '""' , '' , $str);
fputs($openNewData, $unset_emptyArray);

Comment: I have this : "my@exemple.com","125","NY","Wells","tommy","","20130101""hisgoodemail@exemple.com","132","NY","Waits","John","","20120101""goodmail3@exemple.com","222","NY","Wools","John","","20140101"

Comment: I have this : 
"my@exemple.com","125","NY","Wells","tommy","","20130101""hisgoodemail@exemple.com","132","NY","Waits","John","","20120101""goodmail3@exemple.com","222","NY","Wools","John","","20140101"

But I need the new line at at the end of each record ["\n"] like this :
"my@exemple.com","125","NY","Wells","tommy","","20130101"
"hisgoodemail@exemple.com","132","NY","Waits","John","","20120101"
"goodmail3@exemple.com","222","NY","Wools","John","","20140101"

How can I ?

Comment: Rather than using the str_replace, I would opt for something like

`if(empty($arrayContainsFileData)) continue;`

This should skip over empty entries and move on to the next iteration of your outer loop.

To add a new line character at the end of each row, you need to add a new line character to `$str` before `fputs`.  I believe this requires double quotes, so something along the lines of 

`$str = '"' . implode('","', $arrayContainsFileData) . '"' . "\n";`

should work.  I haven't verified that for myself yet.

Comment: Hi cnick,
Many thanks, it works
$str = '"' . implode('","', $arrayContainsFileData) . '"' . "\n"; 
if(empty($arrayContainsFileData)) continue; 
fputs($openNewData, $str);